# Динамически менять изображение og:image созданное в php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

В файле image.php создаётся изображение, в `<img src="/path/image.php?quantity=12" />` оно выводится на странице, а вот если передавать в мета фейсбук:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://url/image.php?quantity=12" />
```

Вот это же изображение не подтягивается и вижу ошибку в debugger facebook:
URL, указанный для og:image (site_url), невозможно обработать как изображение. Недействительный тип контента.
Вопрос, это в принципе возможно и у меня где-то ошибка, или оно в принципе не может так передаваться?

Обновление: если скрапить в дебаггере фейсбук тогда ошибка исчезает, но изображение пустое, не читается.

Comment: а зачем вам тут `php echo` вообще?

Comment: ну я просто убрал переменные из строки и так получилось а так там было $path . /image.php?quantity=$quantity

Comment: просмотрите код страницы и проверьте, что там у вас по факту сгенерировалось. удостоверьтесь также что заголовки отправляются.

Comment: изображение все же имеет смысл сохранят, наверное, и использовать эту копию.